# Extrapolating missing table entries

Tags: sql-server

I'm not sure if this is possible to do in MSSQL. I have a Timesheets table and I would like the user to be able to put in a date range and see all timesheets for that range. The caveat being, that I also want them to view "missing" timesheets.

A user, each week, goes into the Timesheet program and creates a Timesheet. When they're done entering hours, they Submit the Timesheet, then their line manager will Approve the Timesheet (this is relevant, bear with me).

The problem I'm having is if they never create a Timesheet for a given week. I can't quite seem to get it to come out. I have the following query and it will tell me if the user hasn't created a Timesheet for the given range, but if there is say, 3 weeks in the given range and there's a Timesheet for 1 of those weeks, it doesn't report the fact that there's 2 "missing" Timesheets.

```
SELECT U1.Name, T.EndDate,      
    CASE T.Submitted       
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'       
        ELSE 'No'     
    END AS Submitted,   
    CASE T.Approved    
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'    
        ELSE 'No'   
    END AS Approved    
FROM Users U1     
LEFT OUTER JOIN Timesheets T ON U1.idUser = T.id_User AND (T.EndDate <= '2014-10-24' AND T.EndDate >= '2014-10-03')
WHERE U1.Active = 1
ORDER BY U1.Name
```

Technically the two dates will be parameters, I just included them inline to make things a bit easier. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tricks to accomplish this, my favorite being the numbers or tally table. You can quickly and easily make one with one of these to samples(each limited to 5 for the example) or google around for more creative ways to list some numbers.

fancy recursive cte

```
WITH tally ( n ) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 + n FROM tally WHERE n < 5 )
SELECT n FROM tally
```

and one from internal sys tables

```
SELECT number
FROM master..spt_values v
WHERE type = 'P' and number <= 5
```

you can use the list of numbers to join or apply so you have the range without gaps.

Here is an article that explains using a tally to create a daterange, should get you started. [link!](http://www.dbtalks.com/UploadFile/46e60a/generate-date-range-using-tally-tables-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  u.name,
  t.enddate,
  case t.submitted       
      when 1 then 'yes'       
      else 'no'     
  end as submitted,   
  case t.approved    
      when 1 then 'yes'    
      else 'no'   
  end as approved 
from
  timesheets t
cross join
  users u on
  u.iduser = t.id_user
where
  t.enddate <= '2014-10-24' 
  and t.enddate >= '2014-10-03'
  and u.active = 1
```

Comment: No dice on this one. No `ON` clause for `CROSS JOIN` and moving the `ON` clause in your query to the `WHERE` produces the same results as an inner join, which is not what I'm after unfortunately. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Geez i've been out of the game a while. You're problem is that you don't have a table that lists what weeks a timesheet should be submitted for. Is it fair to say that a timesheet should be submitted for EVERY week? If it is, then you could generate a resultset of each week and left join to that.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I might have to do something like that, a timesheet should be submitted EVERY week.